# Why does not the view gets updated in binding?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel, textblock

I am fairly new to MVVM and wpf. I was implementing a simple login page that connects to the database to retrieve user details. In the view model i have a string field called Error that stores any error like wrong password or connection error to show up on view. I bound the error to a textblock in view. So on pressing the login button if some error happens i update the text of error. But the problem is the change is not reflected in view.

```
string _error;
public string Error
    {
        get { return _error; }
        set { _error = value; }
    }
```

update the field as

```
_error = "Wrong password!";
```

In the view:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Error, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

What is the problem?

Edit: I read article on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81484/A-Practical-Quick-start-Tutorial-on-MVVM-in-WPF) and am implementing it in similar way. Still it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send out a property changed event from the ViewModel. The class needs to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface that contains the event you need to fire. The parameter of the event needs to be the name of the property you changed.

Comment: I found a view model base class which implements INotifyPropertyChange, so in my view model class definition i extend view model base class. What else do i need to do?

Comment: @Manoj You find a very good example of what to do in the MSDN documentation. There is a link in my question that leads you to it. Have a look at the examples section.

Answer (score 0):

Add the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` to your ViewModel.

Accept the recommendation for ReSharper to implement the interface for you (you might have to install ReSharper).

In the setter for the property, add `OnPropertyChanged("Error");`.

`Now, if you use`Error ="test";` it will run the setter, which runs the property notify changed, which pushes the change into the View so it can be seen.